# Getting grants of current user in Snowflake

Tags: sql, permissions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to display the grants assigned to current user, when running:

```sql
SHOW GRANTS ON CURRENT_USER();
```

Snowflake returns error:

> Object `'CURRENT_USER'` does not exist or not authorized.

I've tried variations of this query:

```sql
SELECT CURRENT_USER();
SET curr_usr = (SELECT CURRENT_USER());
SHOW GRANTS TO USER $curr_usr;
```

This results in an error:

> syntax error line 1 at position 20 unexpected `'$curr_usr`'.

Running query in the format

```sql
SHOW GRANTS TO USER "someemailaddress@atsomedomain.com";
```

works without a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation...

SHOW GRANTS
Syntactically equivalent to SHOW GRANTS TO USER current_user. Lists all the roles granted to the current user.

I don't believe there is a way to explicitly use the current user with the SHOW GRANTS... syntax. If you do need to do this, rather than just use SHOW GRANTS, then (if you can live with the latency) you can use the view:

```
select *
from SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.GRANTS_TO_USERS
where grantee_name = current_user()
;
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that's a solution. Syntactically, `current_user` returns a string, shame that there is no easy way to push value of that return into `""` of `show grants`...